# MongoDB Contacts to xConnect Migration failing on WFFM analytics data

Tags: wffm, xconnect, mongodb, data-migration

We recently set up a Sitecore 9.1 instance and we are using the xDB migration tool 2.1 to move our old analytics data which were used on Sitecore 8.2 update 6.

We were able to migrate the referencedata with no issue, but when we start the

"MongoDB Contacts to xConnect Migration" pipeline batch, it moves around 1000 records then fails when faced with a record from WFFM with this error:

> ManagedPoolThread #6 07:48:32 ERROR [Data Exchange] Exception while iterating data. (pipeline: Process Single Contact from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Iterate MongoDB Interactions and Run Pipelines, pipeline step identifier: 8adcbb38-793f-44f3-b4db-9eb2ea0fb808)
>
> ManagedPoolThread #6 07:48:32 ERROR [Data Exchange] Element 'Name' does not match any field or property of class Sitecore.DataExchange.Tools.XdbDataMigration.Models.WFFMFieldDataModel. (pipeline: Process Single Contact from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Iterate MongoDB Interactions and Run Pipelines, pipeline step identifier: 8adcbb38-793f-44f3-b4db-9eb2ea0fb808)
>   ManagedPoolThread #6 07:48:32 ERROR [Data Exchange] 
>     at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeClass(BsonDeserializationContext context)
>      at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
>      at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
>      at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize[TNominalType](BsonDocument document, Action`1 configurator)
>      at Sitecore.DataExchange.Tools.XdbDataMigration.DataAccess.Readers.MongoDBCustomValuesForWFFMToXMLReader.GetFieldDataModelListFromArray(BsonArray bsonArray)
>      at Sitecore.DataExchange.Tools.XdbDataMigration.DataAccess.Readers.MongoDBCustomValuesForWFFMToXMLReader.ReadFromArray(BsonArray array, DataAccessContext context)
>      at Sitecore.DataExchange.DataAccess.Mappings.SequentialMappingSet.Run(MappingContext context)
>      at Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.XConnect.DataAccess.Writers.InteractionEventsValueWriter.WriteEvents(IEnumerable eventDataObjects, XObject parentEvent, DataAccessContext context)
>      at Sitecore.DataExchange.DataAccess.Mappings.SequentialMappingSet.Run(MappingContext context)
>      at Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.XConnect.DataAccess.Writers.InteractionEventsValueWriter.WritePageViewEvents(InteractionModel interactionModel, IEnumerable eventDataObjects, DataAccessContext context)
>      at Sitecore.DataExchange.DataAccess.Mappings.SequentialMappingSet.Run(MappingContext context)
>      at Sitecore.DataExchange.ApplyMapping.ApplyMappingStepProcessor.ProcessPipelineStep(PipelineStep pipelineStep, PipelineContext pipelineContext, ILogger logger)
>      at Sitecore.DataExchange.Processors.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor.ProcessPipelineStep(PipelineStep pipelineStep, PipelineContext pipelineContext, ILogger logger)
>      at Sitecore.DataExchange.Processors.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor.ProcessPipeline(Pipeline pipeline, PipelineContext pipelineContext, ILogger logger)
>      at Sitecore.DataExchange.Processors.PipelineSteps.IterateAndRunPipelinesStepProcessor.ProcessPipelines(PipelineStep pipelineStep, ICollection`1 subPipelines, PipelineContext pipelineContext, ILogger logger)
>      at Sitecore.DataExchange.Processors.PipelineSteps.IterateAndRunPipelinesStepProcessor.IterateWithoutThreads(IEnumerable data, ICollection`1 pipelines, Action`1 afterElementHandled, PipelineStep pipelineStep, PipelineContext pipelineContext, ILogger logger)
>      at Sitecore.DataExchange.Processors.PipelineSteps.IterateAndRunPipelinesStepProcessor.ProcessPipelineStep(PipelineStep pipelineStep, PipelineContext pipelineContext, ILogger logger)
>   ManagedPoolThread #6 07:48:32 ERROR [Data Exchange] Pipeline step processing will abort because a critical error occurred during processing. (pipeline: Process Single Contact from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Iterate MongoDB Interactions and Run Pipelines)
>   ManagedPoolThread #6 07:48:32 ERROR [Data Exchange] Sub pipeline processing will abort because a critical error occurred during processing. (pipeline: Process Single Contact from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Iterate MongoDB Interactions and Run Pipelines, pipeline step identifier: 8adcbb38-793f-44f3-b4db-9eb2ea0fb808, sub-pipeline: Process Single Contact from MongoDB Pipeline, sub-pipeline processor: Sitecore.DataExchange.Processors.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor)
>   ManagedPoolThread #6 07:48:32 INFO  [Data Exchange] 1125 elements were iterated before the processor was interrupted. (pipeline: Read Contacts from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Iterate MongoDB Contacts and Run Pipelines, pipeline step identifier: 97e330a3-a2dc-426e-aa1c-02fc407c7a6e)
>   ManagedPoolThread #6 07:48:32 ERROR [Data Exchange] Pipeline step processing will abort because a critical error occurred during processing. (pipeline: Read Contacts from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Iterate MongoDB Contacts and Run Pipelines)
>   ManagedPoolThread #6 07:48:32 ERROR [Data Exchange] Pipeline processing will abort because a critical error occurred during processing. (pipeline batch: MongoDB Contacts to xConnect Migration, pipeline: Read Contacts from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline processor: Sitecore.DataExchange.Processors.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor)

Note: the step that is failing is the following step in the pipeline batch:

`/sitecore/system/Data Exchange/embrace migration/Pipelines/MongoDB Contacts to xConnect Migration Pipelines/Process Single Contact from MongoDB Pipeline/Iterate MongoDB Interactions and Run Pipelines`

We are also open to exclude WFFM data if there is a way to do that in the migration process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following :

1- Navigate to the /sitecore/system/Data Exchange/xDB Data Migration 8x to 9 Branch/Tenant Settings/Providers/xConnect/XObject Mapping Settings/XObject Mapping Definitions/Event Mappings for MongoDB Page Events/Submit Success Event item 
2- In the "Mapping Exclude Conditions" select "Always True codition" 
3- In the Mapping Include - unselect all

After that, try the migration process again

Comment: Just so we are all clear, this just ignores the error and keeps going. I used this also. But I want the OP to know this is skipping data.

Comment: Yep, he mentioned that he wants to exclude the WFFM data, that's why I gave this solution :) Thank you though

Comment: Ahh i missed that. Good to go